# How do I update an entity with nested entities with AutoMapper and save the updated Entity with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I've created a mapping to map a collection in the ViewModel to another collection on a Model which seems to work without a problem. After mapping, The child object of the Model has the appropriate updates.

```
configuration.CreateMap<SourceViewModel, Destination>()                
            .ForMember(d => d.ChildOfDestination, 
                      opt => opt.MapFrom(s => Mapper.Map<ICollection<SourceViewModel>, ICollection<Destination>>(s.ChildOfSource)));
```

However, on save an error is thrown:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

What I have found is ChangeTracker.Entries() has extra items with a state of "Added". For example, my Model.ChildCollection has a count of 2, but in Entries(), I have the original 2 items from ChildCollection with states of "Modified", and 2 of the same items with States of "Added"

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Update([FromBody] SourceViewModel viewModel) {
    var model = await _repository.GetByIdAsync(viewModel.Id);
    Mapper.Map(viewModel, model);
    _repository.Update(model);
    await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
}
```

I wrote some code to get around the problem for the time being but it's a hack to a bigger problem that I'm not sure how to solve.

```
foreach (var child in ViewModel.Child)
{
  var record = Model.Child.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == child.ID);

  if (record != null)
      Mapper.Map(child, record);
  else
      Model.Child.Add(Mapper.Map<SourceViewModel, Destination>(child));
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Entity Framework 6**

> Disconnected data is an old problem that precedes Entity Framework
>   and, for that matter, most data access tools. It’s never been an easy
>   one to solve. The server sends data down the wire, not knowing what
>   may happen to it in the client app that requested it, not even knowing
>   if it will return. Then, suddenly, some data reappears in a request.
>   But is it the same data? What was it up to in its absence? Did
>   anything happen to it? Is it completely new data? So much to worry
>   about!

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/magazine/mt694083

A very good response on this site referring to the article above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21436713/550198

**Entity Framework Core / Entity Framework 7**

Entity Framework Core also known as EF7 has new features that will allow you to walk the object graph. e.g.

```
context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(someEntity,  e => e.Entry.State = EntityState.Added);
```