# Entity Framework: Insert foreign key rows when Update table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

By making use of Entity Framework 6 as well as a repository pattern, I'm trying to update a row, where the existing row has a new foreign key object associated with it. For example a `Person` record already exists. The `Person` get a new `Dog`. So now the `Person` class has a `Dog` property instantiated and populated with data.

This is my update method:

```
public async Task<TObject> UpdateAsync(TObject updated, int key)
{
    if (updated == null)
        return null;

    var existing = await this._context.Set<TObject>().FindAsync(key);
    if (existing != null)
    {
        this._context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(updated);
    }

    await this._context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return existing;
}
```

And I call it by doing the following:

```
personRecord.Dog = new Dog () { Name = "Max", Age = 7 };
await this.PersonRepository.UpdateAsync(personRecord, personRecord.Id)
```

But no new `Dog` record is being inserted into the database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show your `Person` class

Comment: @haim770 `Person` was just an example,  but I'll update question with EF generated models. BTW, when I insert and perform insert code, it works

Comment: SetValues is only going to update the scalar values, not the related properties. Related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426884/generic-repository-to-update-an-entire-aggregate

Comment: @SteveGreene thanks I'll check it out

Comment: @SteveGreene based on the link that you provided, is this the only way this can be done? It feels very cumbersome to implement an interface on all the EF classes

Answer (score 0):

did you check the state of entity person and entity dog ?

the entity state must be in modified state or created  state before saveChange() to

perform the insert

you can check this statut with

`context.Entry(person).State`